# Raphael path not displayed

Tags: javascript, raphael

I believe I have a syntax error, but I have tried everything and can't figure this out.  I am using the Raphael Javascript vector graphics library, and trying to draw a black line from 170, 170 to 150, 150, but nothing is being displayed. Can anyone tell why?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sample-2" style=" background-color:blue; width:500px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var paper = Raphael("sample-2", 900, 500);
            //var curvePath = paper.path("M100,100 L400,400 C500,400 500,100 400,100");
            //curvePath.attr({fill:"blue", stroke:"black"});

            //var circle = paper.circle(175, 175, 50);
            var newpath = paper.path({type:"path", path:"M170, 170 L150, 150", stroke:"black"});
            //circle.attr({"fill": "orange"});
            //circle.attr({"stroke": "black"});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: all i see is a blue background

Comment: your "working" link.  i did all i see is a blue background.  Do you see a black line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing the `Paper.path()` constructor. Call it with a single string argument, representing the path string:

```js
var newpath = paper.path("M170, 170 L150, 150");
```

If you wish to change the path's attributes, e.g. stroke color, fill, fonts use the `attr()` method, like so:

```js
newpath.attr({
    'stroke' : 'black',
    'stroke-width' : 3
});
```

**Raphaël Reference:**

- [`Paper.path()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path)
- [`Element.attr()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr)

Comment: That works, but what if I wanted to change the stroke color within that?  I'm pretty sure I've seen examples where you can do what I'm trying to do, but maybe I'm wrong..

Comment: Thank you.  I see my mistake.  You were very helpful.:)

Comment: Hey, if your still there I changed my code similar to one of the Raphael examples (tiger).  http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html  If you look at the source code it is almost exactly like mine.  But it is still not working.  Can you see why?

Comment: where's the new code? could you post another question regarding this?

Comment: you can't do that. now there's no relation between the original post to the answers, and the benefit of others using it is compromised. i will edit to change it back, please post a new one.

Comment: @PeytonManning If you feel that this answer properly solves your question, you should "accept it" (click the checkmark). You should not change your question to something different; you should ask a new question.